# App crash when deleting post with comments - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I have an app where you can add posts. I recently added the ability to delete the posts also but when a user deletes a post with a comment in it - the app crashes (the post is still deleted though).

The weird part is that I am not getting the error in the tableview where the user deletes the post?

I have a `feedTableViewController` (where the user deletes posts) and a `commentTableViewController`, where people can see the comments of the post.

Even though the user deletes posts in `feedTableViewController`, xcode is showing the error in `commentTableViewController` at this line of code:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(self.dataGotten).child("likesForPost").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot!) in
  if let count: UInt? = snapshot.childrenCount {
     if count! - 1 == 1 {
         self.likesButton.setTitle("\(count! - 1) LIKE", forState: .Normal)
     } else if count! - 1 == 0 {
         self.likesButton.hidden = true
     } else {
         self.likesButton.setTitle("\(count! - 1) LIKES", forState: .Normal)
     }
  }
})
```

As you can probably see the above code is showing how many likes the post has - so it has nothing to do with comments? When deleting a post with likes, the app does NOT crash. When deleting a post with comments the app crashes.. Does anyone know how to get around that?

This is how the deleting of a post looks like in my app:

```
func deletePost(cell: updateTableViewCell) {

  let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Slet", message: "Vil du slette dette?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

   let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Slet", style: .Default) { (_) in

      FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(cell.pathDB).removeValue()

      self.tableView.reloadData()
  }

  let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Annuller", style: .Default) { (_) in       
  }

  alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
  alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

  self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image: Crashing line]

Will provide more code if you need :-)

Comment: Can you provide the console log for the crash?

Comment: My assumption is that it will have something to do with the data you are storing and using to show in the table view. When you delete the post, you reload the table view, but it doesn't look like you update any of the data array that the table view would be referencing to remove the post element.

Comment: @DavidWilliames the console log is saying `(lldb)` and the error I got is added at the bottom of my post now :-)

Comment: Isn't it just weird that I can delete posts with/without likes but as soon as there is comments on the post it crashes, but still deletes the post?

Comment: if the app is crashing at the line `if count! -1 == 1` then I think it would be the forced unwrapping of `count`. Try changing the type of `count` from `UInt?` to `UInt`, then remove the `!` in your if statement

Comment: Create exeption breakpoint first, see if the breakpoint happen in diff place, the problem might be lying in your storyboard also, since you said your code have nothing to do with comment

Comment: @DavidWilliames when doing that it says unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional - even when there aren't comments on the post.

Comment: @D.Finna well then that's probably your problem that will make it crash. Can you just let `count` get it's type implicitly? e.g. `if let count = snapshot.childrenCount {` should optionally unwrap it, only if it is not nil.

Comment: Added your code then I get this error: `Initializer for conditional binding must have an optional type, not UInt`

Comment: @DavidWilliames I found out of something weird.. In the delete function, if I replace deleting the post itself and remove the comments first, then I can delete the post after (after changing the code back to deleting the post instead of just comments) and that gives me no problems.. So I tried to add a delay to deleting the post after deleting comments - but that did not work.. Hmmm..

Comment: @Ramshad it unfortunately does not help with the app crashing :(

Comment: @D.Finna Sorry, I think I may have gone on off on a tangent when I focused on the `count` optionality. To know what is causing the crash we need more detail about the crash log. The single image you added is not enough. There should be a crash log in the console. Can you please provide that. At the moment your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(self.dataGotten).child("likesForPost").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot!) in

 if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
  if let count: UInt = snapshot.childrenCount as UInt {
     if count - 1 == 1 {
         self.likesButton.setTitle("\(count - 1) LIKE", forState: .Normal)
     } else if count - 1 == 0 {
         self.likesButton.hidden = true
     } else {
         self.likesButton.setTitle("\(count - 1) LIKES", forState: .Normal)
     }
  }
 }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not :(

Comment: Could you please try to log the snapshot.childrenCount ? also, you can even check that either child available or not before getting the child count using -hasChild:

Comment: Looking at Firebases API docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot It doesn't appear that `childrenCount` returns an optional. Therefore there's actually no reason to conditionally unwrap it, or conditionally cast it.

Comment: I'm not getting his exact issue. However, hasChild() method should be helpful before calling the snapshot.childrenCount.

Comment: I found out! I added this around the part that got the error: `if count! > 0 { 'code here......' }` - thank you for you help guys :-)

Comment: if snapshot.hasChild() == true will do the same! glad to hear it is resolved.